# How can I get a unique array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, array

The following

```
SELECT ARRAY[a,b,c,d]
FROM ( VALUES
  ('foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz' )
) AS t(a,b,c,d);
```

Returns `{foo,bar,foo,baz}` of type `text[]`. I would like to get `{foo,bar,baz}` of type `text[]` **with one of the duplicate `foo` elements removed**? Does PostgreSQL have a unique function that works on a text-array, or an `anyarray` of `anyelement`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

While there is no function to accomplish that, you can use

1. `unnest()` to convert an array of elements, to a table of rows of one-column,
2. `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates
3. `ARRAY(query)` to recreate the row.

That idiom looks like,

```
ARRAY( SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM unnest(arr) )
```

And in practice is applied like this,

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT e FROM unnest(ARRAY[a,b,c,d]) AS a(e))
FROM ( VALUES
  ('foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz' )
) AS t(a,b,c,d);
```

If you want it sorted you can do,

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT e FROM unnest(ARRAY[a,b,c,d]) AS a(e) ORDER BY e)
FROM ( VALUES
  ('foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz' )
) AS t(a,b,c,d);
```

And that can all can be written with `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` which is **much** cleaner,

```
SELECT ARRAY(
  SELECT DISTINCT e
  FROM ( VALUES
    ('foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz' )
  ) AS t(a,b,c,d)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(ARRAY[a,b,c,d]) AS a(e)
  -- ORDER BY e; -- if you want it sorted
);
```

---

- Answer inspired by RhodiumToad on irc.freenode.net/#postgresql

Answer (score 5):

If the input values are in one column (essentially an array in relational terms), then the unique array can also be obtained using the stock `array_agg()` function with a `DISTINCT` keyword:

```sql
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT v)
FROM ( VALUES
  ('foo'), ('bar'), ('foo'), ('baz')
) AS t(v);
```

Output:

```
   array_agg   
---------------
 {bar,baz,foo}
(1 row)
```

If the input is an array, an `unnest()` can be used to turn the input into a one-column table first, and then `array_agg(DISTINCT ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple function based on @Evan Carroll's answer

```sql
create or replace function array_unique (a text[]) returns text[] as $$
  select array (
    select distinct v from unnest(a) as b(v)
  )
$$ language sql;
```

with that in place you can

```
select internal.array_unique(array['foo','bar'] || array['foo'])

=> {'foo','bar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more of a question / comment.

This code below preserves the original ordering. How can it be improved / made more efficient.

In essence, I believe it will also accomplish the set task.

```
select e
from
(
    select  array_agg(e) over (order by wf_rn) as e, row_number() over (order by wf_rn DESC) as wf_rn 
    from
    (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by e order by wf_rn) as wf_rn_e
        from
        (
            SELECT *, row_number() over () as wf_rn
            FROM 
            ( 
                select unnest(ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz']) as e
            ) AS t
        ) as A
    ) as A
    where wf_rn_e = 1
) as A
where wf_rn = 1
```

I have to say thank you for the "lateral join" pointer - that makes it super easy to execute this without having to wrap it as a function :-)